# how to validate an xml string in java?

Tags: string, validation

I have seen some examples here, which show how to validate an xml File (It´s workking), but my question is: How can I modify this code to validate an String

```
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.*;
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class Validate {  

    public String validaXML(){

        try {
         Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\info.xml"));
         URL schemaFile = new URL("https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd");
         SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
         Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
         Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
         final List exceptions = new LinkedList();
         validator.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler()
          {
          @Override
          public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException
          {
           exceptions.add(exception);
          }
          @Override
          public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException
          {
           exceptions.add(exception);
          }
          @Override
          public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException
          {
           exceptions.add(exception);
          }
          });

         validator.validate(xmlFile);

          } catch (SAXException ex) {
              System.out.println( ex.getMessage());
              return ex.getMessage().toString();

          } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println( e.getMessage());
          return e.getMessage().toString();
         }
        return "Valid";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String res;
       Validate val = new Validate();
       res=val.validaXML();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

I have tried with this:

```
 Source xmlFile = new StreamSource("<Project><Name>sample</Name></Project>");
```

It compiles, but I got this:

> "no protocol: sample"

Thanks for reading I´ll apreciate you opinion

Comment: This should work : `new StreamSource(new StringReader("_your_string_here"))`

Answer (score 5):

The reason why that doesnt work is the constructor your using is `StreamSource(String systemId)`. The String constructor on StreamSource doesnt take xml.

Use the constructor `StreamSource(Reader reader)` and make an reader, such as

```
new StreamSource(new StringReader("xml here"))
```

or you can use the constructor `StreamSource(InputStream inputStream)` as

```
new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream("xml here".getBytes()))
```